# .NET MVC Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For some reason, my route isn't being seen by .NET.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
   "RSSFeed", // Route name
   "Blog/RSSFeed", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Blog", action = "RSSFeed", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "About", // Route name
   "About/", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "About", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Contact", // Route name
  "Contact/", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
           "Admin", // Route name
           "admin/", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Admin", action = "CreatePost", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);       

routes.MapRoute(
         "Resume", // Route name
         "resume/", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Resume", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "ViewArticle", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{friendly}", // URL with parameters
 new {  friendly = "" } // Parameter defaults
);          

 routes.MapRoute(
   "DownloadResume", // Route name
   "DownloadResume/", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Resume", action = "DownloadResume", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );

//Any of these

routes.MapRoute(
    "cpe", // Route name
    "Play/CreatePlayEvent/{groupid}/{username}/{activeplay}/{game}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Play", action = "CreatePlayEvent", groupID = "0", username = "", activeplay = "", game = "" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "CheckPlayEvent", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{groupID}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Play", action = "CheckPlayEvent", groupID = "0" } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
   "clpe", // Route name
   "Play/ClearPlayEvent/{groupid}/{username}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Play", action = "ClearPlayEvent", groupID = "0", username = "" } // Parameter defaults
);

//End broken routes
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

`myurl.com/Play/CheckPlayEvent/0`

Group ID keeps being seen as NULL on the controller side.  Anyone?  Also, there doesn't seem to be a built-in debugger for routing, or at least I haven't seen one.  What does everyone use to debug routes?

Is there a way to say that the Controller name, method name, and parameters make the URL?

Comment: Is the route not working, or are you getting to the controller but with a null groupID? Also, with routing problems, it often helps if we can see all your routes as it is *almost* always an ordering issue / route clash.

Comment: Hey Steve, i've updated with all the routes.  I've tried a myriad different choices... I figured I could just hardcode the controller and action name into the URL segment and just pass in variables as the rest of the segment, apparently that isn't the case.  I was under the impression that each route is unique, defined by the "Route Name"?  CPE, CheckPlayEvent, and clpe are having issues, I can get to the controller, but the param is always null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following route is getting hit, rather that your intended route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
     "ViewArticle", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{friendly}", // URL with parameters
     new {  friendly = "" } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Friendly is optional, so `{controller}/{action}/{id}` style routes will also hit this - which looks really quite like the route you are having trouble with.

Move your play route *above* this one and try again.